# Calculation with preprocessor-defines yields incorrect value

Tags: c, arduino, macros

I am pretty sure it is a common mistake of a beginner but I don't know the correct words for finding an existing answer.

I have defined some consecutive preprocessor macros:

```
#define DURATION        10000
#define NUMPIXELS       60
#define NUMTRANSITION   15
#define UNITS_PER_PIXEL 128
#define R   ((NUMPIXELS-1)/2 + NUMTRANSITION) * UNITS_PER_PIXEL
```

Later I use these values to calculate a value and assign it to a variable. Here two examples:

```
// example 1
uint16_t temp;    // ranges from 500 to 10000
temp = 255 * (temp - 500) / (10000 - 500);
```

Here, `temp` is always `0`. Since my guess was/is an issue with the datatype, I also tried `uint32_t temp`. However, `temp` was always `255` in this case.

```
// example 2
uint32_t h = millis() + offset - t0 * R / DURATION;
```

`millis()` returns an increasing `unsigned long` value (milliseconds since the start). Here, `h` increases a factor of 4 too fast. The same for `unsigned long h`. When I tried a workaround by dividing by `4*DURATION`, `h` was always `0`.

Is it an datatype issue? If or if not, how can I solve it?

Comment: `int` on avrgcc  & g++ is 16 bits. Calculations probably overflow.

Comment: use constants not defines

Comment: Also, if you do use defines, put them in parens, especially if it's more than just a number, like `R`

Comment: @P__J__: That's what I already mentioned in my post.
@Juraj: Macros/defines are replaced by the pre-processor. Thus, the compiler gets only constants like in example 1 which does not use macros/defines at all.
@CherryDT: You're right, I changed it in my code. Luckily, `R` is a product so that no summation/subtractions has interfered with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works on Arduino Uno and an ESP32 as expected

```
    #define DURATION        10000
    #define NUMPIXELS       60
    #define NUMTRANSITION   15
    #define UNITS_PER_PIXEL 128
    #define R   ((NUMPIXELS-1)/2 + NUMTRANSITION) * UNITS_PER_PIXEL
    uint32_t t0 = millis();

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin (115200);
      //Later I use these values to calculate a value and assign it to a variable. Here two examples:

      // example 1

      randomSeed(721);
    }

    void loop() {
     // For UNO /ESP use uint16_t temp = random(500,10000);    // ranges from 500 to 10000
     // for ATtiny85 (DigiSpark)
    uint32_t temp = random(500,10000);    // ranges from 500 to 10000
      temp = 255 * (temp - 500) / (10000 - 500);

      // Here, temp is always 0. Since my guess was / is an issue with the datatype, I also tried uint32_t temp. However, temp was always 255 in this case.

      // example 2
      Serial.println(temp);
      uint16_t offset = random(2000, 5000);
      uint32_t h = millis() + offset - t0 * R / DURATION;
      Serial.println(h);
    delay (5000); // Only to prevent too much Serial data, never use in production
    }
```

Environment ArduinoIDE 1.8.12/ avr core 1.8.2 and ESP32 1.04. 
What hardware are you compiling to? Try the test program, it does (at least on the tested hardware) what it should.
EDIT: For reference OP uses Attiny85 (Digispark) where var size defs are more critical than on UNO /ESP -instead of Serial you would use SerialUSB. 
Tip for future support requesters -> always reference your environment (HW & SW) with microcontrollers because of possible hardware specific issues

Comment: I compile to an ATtiny85 (DigiSpark). Thus, I had to use `SerialUSB` instead. Thanks to your suggestion, I figured out that `h` was always working - I only misinterpreted the temporal behavior before. Anyway, `temp` is not working in your code because it yields values from 0..6 only. After declaring it as `uint32_t` (and fixing some other code which was responsible for "always 255" before) it is working. If you correct and highlight the latter one, I mark your answer as accepted.